# How Can I Get a Stack Trace of Node/Mocha Errors Outside of It Statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

When I run my Mocha test suite through Node.js and the code gets an error, Node outputs the stack trace of that error ... unless it's a TypeError caused by making a call on an undefined variable, in which case I get no stack trace or test failure at all, just a single line of output.

For instance, if I have the following code:

```
foo.bar(); // foo is undefined
```

I just get:

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined]
```

when I run Mocha.

Is there any way to make Node/Mocha output the full stack trace of such errors?  Without that its difficult to find the problem its complaining about.

**EDIT:** Actually, it seems like the problem also has something to do with where the error occurs.  If it happens inside a `describe` I don't get a stack trace, but if they happen inside an `it` I do.  Is there any way to get errrors in `describe`s (or anywhere else without a stack trace) to show their stack trace?

Comment: i've been wondering the same thing